# How to copy fzf preview window directly to the terminal

Tags: fzf

Is there a way to print the contents of the fzf preview window directly to the terminal? The only way I have found so far is to repeat everything in the --bind section, then pass the result to xclip and flush out xclip once I leave fzf.

```
$ find ~  -not -path '*/.*'  -type d | nl | fzf --preview='du -sh {2}; echo;  ls {2} | cat -n; stat {2}' --bind 'enter:execute((du -sh {2}; echo;  ls {2} | cat -n; stat {2}) | xclip)+accept'

$ xclip -o
```

Replacing **| xclip** by **> /dev/pts/0** or **> /dev/tty** doesn't work.